# How to Install Flutter using fvm(Flutter Version Manager?), I have tried this command but it is not working(fvm install 3.7.6)?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development, fvm

I just Added fvm using homebrew then I have tried to install flutter sdk using fvm - (Flutter version Manager) I have used this command - "fvm install 3.7.6"  but I'm getting this error.

[Please help me to fix this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipSX7.png)

Comment: could you add the error as a code snippet instead? what's the OS that you're using?

Comment: you can also include output after running the command with --verbose option

Answer (score 0):

You should thank the producers of FVM for their great work over the years, but there's a new player in town: `puro`.

Puro is faster, more space-efficient, and interacts more closely with shells and IDEs.  Instead of multiple, nearly-identical installs of various versions, Puro relies on the knowledge that a Flutter release is a git repo, and effectively downloads and stores only the diffs between releases.

Check it out at https://puro.dev/.

(Plus, as an easter egg, check out `puro eval`.)